# Find and replace in Word with wildcards

Tags: ms-word, wildcard

I want to replace all instances of `.` with `,` in Word.

I want to find `([0-9]).([0-9])` and replace it with `\1,\2`. But it is changing `0.72` to `07,2` when I want `0,72`.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: You are aware that `.` means "absolutely any character" aren't you?

Comment: Those aren't regular expressions what **Word** offers and it calls it "use wildcards" for that reason. Hence, `.` has no special meaning ([see](https://wordmvp.com/FAQs/General/UsingWildcards.htm)) and I don't understand that outcome for you either. Which version are you using?

Comment: Here, it works the way you would expect. Do you have a mix of LTR and RTL text in your document?

Answer (score 1):

To match the `.` character literally you should add a `\` character before the **.** like this

```
([0-9]+)\.([0-9]+)
```

And to allow many Number characters before and after the `.` you can add **+** sign after each list of character (**[0-9]**)